# Teradata SQL Split Single String into Table Rows

Tags: teradata-sql-assistant

I have one string element, for example :

```
"(1111, Tem1), (0000, Tem2)"
```

and hope to generate a data table such as

| var1 | var2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1111 | Tem1 |
| 0000 | Tem2 |

This is my code, I created the lag `token` and filter with odd rows element.

```
with var_ as (
    select '(1111, Tem1), (0000, Tem2)' as pattern_
)
select tbb1.*, tbb2.result_string as result_string_previous
from(
    select tb1.*,
        min(token) over(partition by 1 order by token asc rows between 1 preceding and 1 preceding) as min_token
    from
        table (
            strtok_split_to_table(1, var_.pattern_, '(), ')
            returns (outkey INTEGER, token INTEGER, result_string varchar(20))
        ) as tb1) tbb1

inner join (select min_token, result_string from tbb1) tbb2
    on tbb1.token = tbb2.min_token

where (token mod 2) = 0;
```

But it seems that i can't generate new variables in "from" step and applied it directly in "join" step.
so I wanna ask is still possible to get the result what i want in my procedure? or is there any suggestion?

Thanks for all your assistance.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't split / recombine the groups. Split each group to a row, then split the values within the row, e.g.

```
with var_ as (
    select '(1111, Tem1), (0000, Tem2)' as pattern_
),
split1 as (
    select trim(leading '(' from result_string) as string_  
    from
        table ( /* split at & remove right parenthesis */
            regexp_split_to_table(1, var_.pattern_, '\)((, )|$)','c')
            returns (outkey INTEGER, token_nbr INTEGER, result_string varchar(256))
        ) as tb1
)
select *
    from table(
            csvld(split1.string_, ',', '"')
            returns (var1 VARCHAR(16), var2 VARCHAR(16))
        ) as tb2
;
```